# How to produce lighter mongodb c++ driver

Tags: mongodb, visual-studio-2012, compilation, scons

I'm compiling mongoclient with MSVC 2012 and boost 1.54 and the generated lib size is about 117 mb !
I am doing something wrong ?

I'm using this command:

```
scons --extrapath=c:\dev\boost_1_54_0 --release --32 mongoclient
```

Answer (score 0):

Self response: The huge size is due to 2 things : static library and debugging symbols non stripped from it. Version 2.5 will produce dynamic lib (dll) and separate debugging symbol (pdb).